# 'pip install pymongo' stopped working

Tags: python, mongodb

What do I do wrong?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==7.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-    py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
ImportError: No module named 'pip'
```

Stackoverflow asked me to type more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more

Comment: At first you should replace your placeholder text with a description of what you did to get the error.

Comment: Here lies your error `ImportError: No module named 'pip'`

Comment: Yes, but what do I do with that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to fix pip installation with:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

I've had the same issue and this worked for me. Maybe it's because you only installed pip for an earlier version of python or you intalled it from source and not from you distributions package management.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your pip variable isn't set or you're trying to use conflicting environments. If you want to get the python package pymongo installed on your 3.4 version look to use:

```
/usr/local/bin/pip3.4 install pymongo
```

Then you can verify by testing in the 3.4 interpreter by running:

```
python3.4
>>>import pymongo
>>>
```

In the future look at using virtualenvs, they can be really easy and clean to work with while controlling your packages neatly. Hope this helps!

Comment: No luck I am afraid
/usr/local/bin/pip3.4 install pymongo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3.4", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==7.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip3.4')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-<...>
$ python3.4
>>> import pymongo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pymongo'